# How do I call a method from aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm trying to call a method from my aspx file, same class as defined in Page `Inherit`.

The method is defined like this:

in **foo.aspx.cs**

```
   public void GeneratePartiesOptionsList()
        {
           //parties is a non-empty static readonly array of string[] type
            Debug.WriteLine("GeneratePartiesOptionsList() called");
            foreach(string party in parties)
            {
                Response.Write(string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{0}</option>{1}", party, Environment.NewLine));
            }
        }
```

and from foo.aspx, I call like this:

```
<select id="list" runat="server">
                            <%
                                this.GeneratePartiesOptionsList();
                             %>
                        </select>
```

But when I open **foo.aspx** page I didn't get anything, neither the contents that I wanted to generate nor errors. The select is empty. What am I missing? I'm new to ASP.NET/WebForms.

Comment: Can you pls tell us why you would populate select list with `Response.Write` instead of data binding?

Comment: Because I'm new to ASP.NET and I don't know about that. Would you please give an example of a better way to do that?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtInside" runat="server" Width="60px"  Text='<%# ShowMeQte() %>' ></asp:TextBox>  that is for a text box, and the c# function returns a string, like philip pittle suggest, now for a <select> ... i guess it works the same, maybe not

Comment: I'm using `list.Items.Add()` now. Move `GeneratePartiesOptionsList()` call to constructor. Works just fine! But if there's a better way to do that I'd like to hear too. the <% %> are ugly. I used because I don't know something else instead of

Comment: @Jack The way you are doing is really weird in **ASP.Net Web Form**. Can you not able to use **DropDownList** server control? If not, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As someone new to .net you may think that making any html runat="server" gives it something special. What you are trying to do is accomplished with an asp:dropdownlist  using it's binding parameters.  this doesn't answer your question the way you asked it but gets the task you are trying to accomplish done.

Comment: @Win: I didn't know about this method when I created the thread. I'm using `list.Items.Add()` now

Answer (score 2):

So, `Response.Write` is generally a bad idea in ASP.NET because it's going to run at a different time than you expect. Odds are your expected text is somewhere on the delivered page (I think it'll be at the bottom), but not in a useful block of HTML.

If you want to go this route, then you want your code behind method to return a `string` and then use the `<%= this.GeneratePartiesOptionsList() %>` syntax, which will get ASP.NET to output it where you expect.

You should look at data-binding though, because writing out HTML like this is swimming upstream for WebForms....

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly using the `<% %>` syntax, your method needs to return a `string` and that string is written directly to the Response by the aspx page.  So:

```
public string GeneratePartiesOptionsList()
{
       //parties is a non-empty static readonly array of string[] type
        Debug.WriteLine("GeneratePartiesOptionsList() called");

        return string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine
            parties.Select(
               party => 
                string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{0}</option>", party));
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to use the platform-dependent `Environment.NewLine` for stuff that is going to be output to other computers. Rather use `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` depending on what you use for your HTML code elsewhere.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - that's an interesting point.  I generally use `Environment.NewLine` because it's supposed to get the correct NewLine character for the current execution environment.  It shouldn't matter so much for an HTML document as the whitespace is generally ignored, but if the OP runs into an issue, then it should certainly be updated.

Comment: It's not a real issue in HTML because whitespace is ignored. But the point is when you're sending data to somebody else or storing it in a file that might be sent to somebody else, you do *not* want the newline for the current environment, you want the exact correct one. `Environment.NewLine` is useful for things such as console output and creating files that are to be used locally only.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInside" runat="server" Text='<%# ShowMeQte() %>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

maybe it's just the # your missing ?

Comment: the # is a data bound symbol for passing in something to be interpreted by the control you are passing it to. It doesn't work unless used like you have it here, inside of another control.